# I was programming in python and I am stuck with making a binary file

Tags: python, file-io, binary

So I want to make a binary file in Python but it gives a error

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
> Here is my code

```
with open('test.binary','wb') as f:
    f = f.write('Hello!')
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open a file as binary, you have to encode strings as bytes:

```
with open('test.binary','wb') as f:
    f = f.write('Hello!'.encode())
```

Or use `b` as as prefix of your string:

```
with open('test.binary','wb') as f:
    f = f.write(b'Hello!')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck with this for a while. You helped me out!